# Linear Regression: Line fits, but cost seems to increase

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to implement linear regression, but when I plot the cost, the value goes down initially, then very slowly starts increasing after about 10,000 iterations. Strange thing is, with increasing iterations the line fits the data better, but the cost is still going up.

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong when computing the cost or plotting the cost, but I can't figure it out. I've tried smaller learning rates and the same thing happens, just slower.

[GitHub Gist of the notebook](https://gist.github.com/florestony54/3ab5ec80409c2a76470f842f9ec491ce)

Comment: How are you calculating "the line fits the data better"? Ordinarily, it should be the cost : lower cost means the line fits better, but you are claiming that line is fitting better, but cost is going up

Comment: Honestly I guess I'm just eyeballing it. I don't know if you were able to see the plots on the Gist I linked, but the line looked like it was aligning with the data better. Also, when I created the dataset I basically gave it a slope of 3 with 'y= 3*x + (np.random.rand(100,))' so I'd expect the regression model to hit somewhere close to h0=3

Comment: Please post the necessary code here, not in an external repo; see how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your cost function is wrong. You are using `x_pred` for getting `y_predict` and then you are comparing `y_predict` with `y_actual`, BUT `y_actual` values are corresponding to `x`, not `x_pred`

your code:

```
def cost_fxn(alpha, beta, y_actual):
    cost = 0
    y_predict = y_pred(alpha, beta, x_pred)
    for i in range(100):
        sq_error = (y_actual[i] - y_predict[i])**2
        cost += sq_error
    return cost/(2*100)
```

it should be:

```
def cost_fxn(alpha, beta, y_actual):
    cost = 0
    y_predict = y_pred(alpha, beta, x)
    for i in range(100):
        sq_error = (y_actual[i] - y_predict[i])**2
        cost += sq_error
    return cost/(2*100)
```

I ran this code and got:
[image]